# I'm trying to get a specific string of the json file

Tags: java, json, reddit

I'm trying to get the author or other things like the thumbnail url via the json file of reddit. But if i'll run it, its only responding with a error: `com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException`

I am using Java with the jsonpath api to get the path.

Code:

```
String url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/new.json?sort=new";
```

**...**

```
System.out.println("result after Reading JSON Response");
String json = response.toString();
Object document = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(json);

String author0 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.data[0].children[0].data.author");

System.out.println(author0);
```

Everything is working except of that i can't get the value of author0

**EDIT:** I want to know the author, but i doesn't work. The Response String and JSON String are right (*https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/new.json?sort=new*)

Comment: What is your question about this error?

Comment: I updated the text with usefull informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to get the author name;

```
String author0 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.data.children[0].data.author_fullname");
```